# Portlet JSP: How to create a serie of ActionURL based on an array of values

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet

In a portlet JSP I need to generate a serie of AcctionURL ciclying over an array of values.

All is ok in the below code that I used to genarate the serie of RenderURL:

```
<%
            PortletURL manageReportURL = renderResponse.createRenderURL();
                manageReportURL.setParameter("jspPage", "/html/ManageDossier/manageReport.jsp");
                manageReportURL.setParameter("dossierEntryIds", primKey);
                manageReportURL.setParameter("redirect", rowURL);
            for (int w = 0; w < csApps.size(); w++) {
                manageReportURL.setParameter("csAppReportId", String.valueOf(csApps.get(w).getCompanyStudioAppId()));
        %>
                <liferay-ui:icon image="category" message="<%= csApps.get(w).getDescription() %>" url="<%= manageReportURL.toString() %>" />
        <%
            }
        %>
```

I used the same kind of code of the ResourceURL and all is ok:

```
<%
        ResourceURL serveResourceURL = renderResponse.createResourceURL();
            serveResourceURL.setParameter("dossierId", primKey);
        for (int n = 0; n < csAppsNoParms.size(); n++) {
            serveResourceURL.setParameter("csAppReportId", String.valueOf(csAppsNoParms.get(n).getCompanyStudioAppId()));
    %>
            <liferay-ui:icon image="print" message="<%= LanguageUtil.get(themeDisplay.getLocale(), \"print\") + StringPool.SPACE + csAppsNoParms.get(n).getDescription() %>" url="<%= serveResourceURL.toString() %>" />
    <%
        }
    %>
```

But when I'll do the same thing for the ActionURL, I got no errors but my action code is never executed - simply nothing is done:

```
<%
        PortletURL notifyDossierToDittaURL = renderResponse.createActionURL();
            notifyDossierToDittaURL.setParameter("resourcePrimKey", primKey);
            notifyDossierToDittaURL.setParameter("redirect", rowURL);
        for (int n = 0; n < msgContentToDittaCodes.length; n++) {
            notifyDossierToDittaURL.setParameter("msgContentCod", msgContentToDittaCodes[n]);
    %>      
            <liferay-ui:icon image="news" message="<%= LanguageUtil.get(themeDisplay.getLocale(), \"send\") + StringPool.SPACE + msgContentToDittaCodes[n] %>" url="<%= notifyDossierToDittaURL.toString() %>" />
    <%
        }
    %>
```

Please, anyone can see the difference between the above createRenderURL() and createActionURL()  ?

Or address me to generate a serie of ActionURL based on an array of values ?

Thank you in advance,
Ivano C.

Comment: Do you have only one processAction() method in your portlet? Please post your portlet code here as well.

Comment: Hi Thakkar, thank you for your question.  Thanks to the MVCPortlet kind of portlet from Liferay, I can have more than one processAction(), for example the JSP code in my initial question calls the below method:

public void notifyDossierToDittaURL(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws SystemException, IOException, PortalException {  }

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Liferay's MVCPortlet, I am assuming you have different 'action' methods in your portlet code - each having different names of-course. Your code doesn't seem to let MVCPortlet know which action method to call. You will need to add below line to your code:

```
String actionName = "yourMvcPortletActionMethodName";
notifyDossierToDittaURL.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME, actionName);
```

There is a better ways to create ActionURL in your portlet JSP:

`<portlet:actionURL var="notifyDossierToDittaURL" name="yourMvcPortletActionMethodName"></portlet:actionURL>`

I recommend using the above syntax as compared to scriptlets in a JSP.